# In-process persistant key-value store for node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a need to store some meta-data in a node.js application I am writing. Rather than come up with my own file format and managing that file, I would like to use an in-process persistant key-value store.

I was looking at mongodb but it seems that mongodb must always be run out-of-process (that is, you need to start a mongo server first, then connect to it in node.js.) I require that whatever store this is, that it exist entirely within the node.js process - or at least that any external processes are entirely managed transparently by the library, and kills them when the application closes the connection.

I don't care much about performance, but it would be nice to support asynchronous IO to the store to keep up with Node's whole async thing.

It would also be nice if the store supported indexes, as I will definitely be querying the data in a way where indexes would be helpful.

I'm pretty sure that 'sqlite' would work for me, except that I don't really see it as being nearly as convenient as a key-value store. Ideally I should be able to speak in JSON, not SQL. But sqlite will work if nothing better exists.

Thanks!

Comment: Please could you explain _why_ you subject yourself to this constraint?

Comment: Use a Javascript object. If you have only one process, then asynchrony is moot.

Comment: do yoy really need a database for persisting "some metadata"? I don't think so.

Comment: @MattHickford - Which constraint? The reason I want it to be in-process is because I would like the end user to be able to install this program and run it in a cron job, without having to spin up a helper process to run the database. Javascript Objects are fine except that I will need to run queries like "get all objects with property X greater than this value", and I strongly suspect that with a few hundred thousand entries that would run very slowly.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas - Well I definitely need to persist the relevant meta-data of a few hundred thousand files, and I would like to be able to query it faster than simply looping over an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in using redis http://redis.io/

There is a popular helper library for node https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Then you can do this:

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

client.set("foo_rand000000000000", "OK");
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be in-process - it requires an externally running server process.

Comment: In the end, I went with this. To make it seem like a single process to the end-user, I spin up a local redis server on an unprivileged port from within node using `child_process.spawn`, and make sure to tear it down before exiting.

Thanks fo the suggestion!

Comment: That's quite a novel approach. Glad you got it working. Hopefully packaging the redis install as part of your app is not too troublesome.

Comment: Would really like to know how you spawned the server from Node.js. Any links? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try nStore.
https://github.com/creationix/nstore

It's in process key-value store.  Simple to use as well.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to https://github.com/sergeyksv/tingodb. It is closely compatible to MongoDB API so you can upgrade to MongoDB when you'll need it.

Comment: Thanks, good tip. Useful in cases where you'd like to bundle a DB in your node library, but want to support better scalable solutions as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be interested in [final-db](https://github.com/finalclass/finaldb).

FinalDB uses file system to store it's data. It's not key-value store but **document-based** nosql solution. It supports indexes (maps) - you can specify **map functions** on each collection and of course it's an **in process** solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [levelup](https://github.com/rvagg/node-levelup). This a wrapper around [leveldb](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/). The levelup wrapper installs leveldb via npm and runs entirely within your node process.

There are many databases built on top of leveldb. Take a look at https://github.com/rvagg/node-levelup/wiki/Modules for a list.

For convenience you can use the [level](https://github.com/Level/level) package which bundles both levelup and leveldown together

Answer (score -1):

How about...

```
var store = { };

//store 'myKey'
store.myKey = { foo: 'bar' };

//fetch 'myKey'
var x = store.myKey;
```

Also, Googling with almost exactly your question title, you would have found http://pgte.github.com/alfred/

I don't really think there are very many particularily stable ones available yet. The external offerings are quite good though (eg. Redis)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Alfred is a real possibility, but you're right, it doesn't strike me as being hugely stable - but definitely worth a shot.

A simple object store like you propose might work, but I suspect it will choke when I run 'queries' like "get all objects with property X greater than such a value", given that I will have a few hundred thousand entries.

Comment: @eblume yeah it's quite possible.. You would need to come up with some indexing scheme for it. I'd really just go with mongo or redis if possible, both are quite simple to set up.

Comment: I agree that it seems simple to interface with an existing redis instance or to start up a permanent local redis instance... but I wonder how difficult/reasonable it would be to start a redis instance from within a node app, use it a little, then shut it down when you are done?

I suppose using the `child_process` module that could work.